# MPI_Barrier doesn't seem to work, reordering printf (stdout) messages

Tags: c, mpi

Below is a very basic MPI program

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Hello from %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Goodbye from %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Hello 2 from %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Goodbye 2 from %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

You would expect the output to be (for 2 processes)

```
Hello from 0
Hello from 1
Goodbye from 1
Goodbye from 0
Hello 2 from 1
Hello 2 from 0
Goodbye 2 from 0
Goodbye 2 from 1
```

Or something similar (the hellos and goodbyes should be grouped, but process order is not guaranteed).

Here is my actual output:

```
Hello from 0
Goodbye from 0
Hello 2 from 0
Goodbye 2 from 0
Hello from 1
Goodbye from 1
Hello 2 from 1
Goodbye 2 from 1
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding what MPI_Barrier is supposed to do? From what I can tell, if I use it only once, then it gives me expected results, but any more than that and it seems to do absolutely nothing.

I realize many similar questions have been asked before, but the askers in the questions I viewed misunderstood the function of MPI_Barrier.

Comment: @Zulan, I think you are correct. I have marked my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> the hellos and goodbyes should be grouped

They should not, there is additional (MPI-asynchronous) buffering inside `printf` function, and other one buffering is `stdout` gathering from multiple MPI processes to single user terminal.

`printf` just prints into in-memory buffer of libc (glibc), which is sometimes flushed to real file descriptor (`stdout`; use `fflush` to flush the buffer); and `fprintf(stderr,...)` usually have less buffering than `stdout`

Remote tasks are started by mpirun/mpiexec, usually with `ssh` remote shell, which does `stdout`/`stderr` forwarding. `ssh` (and TCP too) will buffer data and there can be reordering when data from `ssh` is showed at your terminal by mpirun/mpiexec or other entity (several data streams are multiplexed into one).

What you get is like 4 strings from first process are buffered and flushed at its exit (all strings were printed to `stdout` with usually has buffer of several kilobytes); and 4 more strings from second process are buffered too till exit. All 4 strings are sent by `ssh` or other launch method to your console as single "packet" and your console just shows both packets of 4 lines each in some order, either "4_lines_packet_from_id_0; 4_lines_packet_from_id_1;" or as "4_lines_packet_from_id_1;4_lines_packet_from_id_0;".

> MPI_Barrier is supposed to do?

`MPI_Barrier` synchronizes parts of code, but it can't disable any buffering in libc/glibc printing and file I/O functions, nor in `ssh` or other remote shell.

If all of your processes run on machines with synchronized system clocks (they will be when you have single machine and they should be when there is `ntpd` on your cluster), you can add timestamp field to every `printf` to check that real order is respecting your barrier (`gettimeofday` looks for current time, and has no extra buffering). You may sort timestamped output even if `printf` and `ssh` will reorder messages.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_timestamped_message(int mpi_rank, char *s);
{
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    printf("[%u.%06u](%d): %s\n", now.tv_sec, now.tv_usec, mpi_rank, s);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_timestamped_message(rank, "First Hello");
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_timestamped_message(rank, "First Goodbye");
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_timestamped_message(rank, "Second Hello");
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_timestamped_message(rank, "Second Goodbye");
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that assumption about `gettimeofday` would hold on many distributed systems. NTP is by no means accurate enough. If you must make some ordering, just increment a counter on each barrier.

Comment: Zulan, how fast is Barrier and how accurate is NTP in typical clusters?

Comment: Barrier is typically 10-100 us (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5493494/), NTP has around 1ms under ideal conditions (https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/exec.html).